# Starting training takes a very long time in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Tensorflow 2 takes about 15 minutes to make its static graph (or whatever it's doing before the first pass). The training time after this is normal, but obviously it's hard to experiment with 15 mins of waiting for any feedback.

The generator encoder and discriminator are RNNs (not unrolled) with GRU cells in a Keras model.

The generator decoder is defined and called like this:

```
class GeneratorDecoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, feature_dim):
    super(GeneratorDecoder, self).__init__()
    self.cell = tf.keras.layers.GRUCell(
        GRUI_DIM, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='sigmoid',
        dropout=DROPOUT, recurrent_dropout=DROPOUT)
    self.batch_normalization = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
    self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
        feature_dim, activation='tanh')

@tf.function
def __call__(self, z, timesteps, training):
    # z has shape (batch_size, features)
    outputs = []
    output, state = z, z
    for i in range(timesteps):
        output, state = self.cell(inputs=output, states=state,
                                  training=training)
        dense_output = self.dense(
            self.batch_normalization(output))
        outputs.append(dense_output)
    return outputs
```

Here is my training loop (the mask_gt and missing_data variables are cast using tf.cast and should so already be tensors):

```
for it in tqdm(range(NO_ITERATIONS)):
   print(it)
   train_step()


@tf.function
def train_step():
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        generator_output = generator(missing_data, training=True)
        imputed_data = get_imputed_data(missing_data, generator_output)
        mask_pred = discriminator(imputed_data)
        D_loss = discriminator.loss(mask_pred, mask_gt)
        G_loss = generator.loss(missing_data, mask_gt,
                                generator_output, mask_pred)
    gen_enc_grad = tape.gradient(
        G_loss, generator.encoder.trainable_variables)
    gen_dec_grad = tape.gradient(
        G_loss, generator.decoder.trainable_variables)
    disc_grad = tape.gradient(
        D_loss, discriminator.model.trainable_variables)
    del tape

    generator.optimizer.apply_gradients(
        zip(gen_enc_grad, generator.encoder.trainable_variables))
    generator.optimizer.apply_gradients(
        zip(gen_dec_grad, generator.decoder.trainable_variables))
    discriminator.optimizer.apply_gradients(
        zip(disc_grad, discriminator.model.trainable_variables))
```

Note that "0" is printed within a few seconds, so the slow part is definitely not earlier.
And this is the get_imputed_data function that is called:

```
def get_imputed_data(incomplete_series, generator_output):
    return tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(incomplete_series), generator_output, incomplete_series)
```

Thanks for any answers! Hope I provided just enough code to give a sense of where the problem lies. This is my first time posting here after reading for at least five years :)

I use Python 3.6 and Tensorflow 2.1.

Comment: How about profiling the code? This would give you a detailed answer. Also, make sure to switch `logging` to `DEBUG` mode.

Comment: Cool, didn't know tf had a debug mode! Just the normal cProfile mode in python didn't lead to any insights, but maybe this will :) I'll respond when it finishes in 15 minutes.

Comment: Almost all the time was spent creating the graph, as suspected. However, when playing around with removing @ tf.function from the __call__ function for the components, the graph creation time dropped to just over a minute! That's completely fine for my purposes. Apparently I need to do some reading on exactly what @ tf.function does :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing the tf.function decorator for the calling functions of the generator and discriminator. I was using a single global python scalar (the iteration no.) in two of the tf.function decorated functions. This caused a new graph to be created every time (see the caution [in the tf.function docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function)).

The solution is to drop the python variables used or convert them to tensorflow variables.